# Q async library with node.js waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q, mean-stack

I'm really struggling with the Q module in nodejs.

This is my code below. It works fine on runnable.com but when I put it in one of my controller methods (as is), it just keeps waiting and I can tell its invoked the first method. but it just keeps waiting. What am I doing wrong. I've already spent 2 days on this now :(

```
var Q = require('q');

function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";

    this.getInfo = function() {
        console.log(this.color);
        return;
    };
}

var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
apple.color = "reddish";

var stat = Q.ninvoke(apple, 'getInfo').then(function() { console.log(err) });
```

Update:

Changed Q.ninvoke to Q.invoke and using v2.0 of Q, this is no longer available. I get the error invoke is undefined.

Changed to using v1.0 of Q and now the following works just fine.

```
var Q = require('q');

function Apple(type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";

    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color;
    };
}

var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
apple.color = "reddish";

Q.invoke(apple, 'getInfo')
    .then(function(color) {
        console.log(color);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Actually, its not executing the then block in either case! Please help

Comment: Straight from [the docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args), emphasis mine: *"`ninvoke` Calls **a Node.js-style method** with the given variadic arguments, returning a promise that is fulfilled if the method **calls back with a result**, or rejected if it **calls back with an error**."* - Your `getInfo()` does neither, so of course this can never work.

Comment: @Tomalak what do you mean by getInfo() does nothing.

Comment: That sentence from the documentation could not be any clearer, really. I've even made the relevant parts bold in my comment.

Comment: so how would void functions work then?

Comment: Through `invoke` instead of `ninvoke`. I've seen only now that you've been using the v2 branch of Q. Apparently that's still WIP.

Comment: Yeah I've moved back to v1 now. I think I'm getting a handle on this now. Its all new to me node and q, even the concept of the promise is very new. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: Admittedly the concept of promises and asynchronous program flow is a pretty advanced one if you're all new to that facet of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Q.ninvoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args), expects a Node.js style method. Node.js style methods accept a callback function and that function will be invoked with the error or with the result of the execution.

So, your program will work, if you can change your `getInfo` function to accept a callback function and invoke it when the result has to be returned, like this

```
var Q = require('q');

function Apple(type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";

    this.getInfo = function(callback) {
        return callback(null, this.color);
    };
}

var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
apple.color = "reddish";

Q.ninvoke(apple, 'getInfo')
    .then(function(color) {
        console.log(color);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

**Note:** Since  you are not using Node.js style method, you should use [`Q.invoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseinvokemethodname-args) instead of `Q.ninvoke` like this

```
var Q = require('q');

function Apple(type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";

    this.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color;
    };
}

var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
apple.color = "reddish";

Q.invoke(apple, 'getInfo')
    .then(function(color) {
        console.log(color);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Either the documentation is not clear or I'm a complete noob. I had to change fail to catch though as its deprecated.

Comment: @user3428172 What is the version of `q` you are using?

Comment: @user3428172 What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: invoke is undefined or something similar. I can see that github says 2.0 is experimental so I should be using 1?

Comment: @user3428172 Please edit the question with the **exact error information**, only then I can help you :(

Comment: Done. I ended up going down to v1.0 of Q to make it work without changing to using node style.

Comment: @user3428172 Glad to have been of little help :)